# Ubuntu 16.04LTS - pwquality.conf & pam_pwquality registering incorrect passwords, but approves them anyway

Tags: 16.04, password, pam, passwd

I'm working on implementing password quality requirements in Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS. I have configured 'pwquality.conf' with the requirements and '/etc/pam.d/common-password' to add pam_pwquality.so to the stack. When I attempt to change the password for a user using an obviously inadequate password, it returns an error saying that it doesn't meet the requirements, but then approves it anyway.

Here's my common-password config:

```
password    requisite                     pam_pwquality.so retry=2
password    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512 rounds=5000 remember=5
password    requisite                     pam_deny.so
password    requisite                     pam_permit.so
password    optional                      pam_encrypt.so
```

The process of changing my password with a password that obviously does not meet requirements is as follows:

```
#sudo passwd test
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD:The password contains less than 1 digits
Retype new password: 
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Would appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change your password within the userspace of the user test?
If you try to change it via sudo/root you bypass the rules unless you put an additional "enforce_for_root" behind your pam_pwquality.so call.

You should do the following:

```
#> su test -
#> passwd
```

If the quality is not enforced after that, then there must be some additional error in your config.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following phrase of enforce_for_root: This ensures that the password policies are adhered to even if it’s the root user configuring the passwords.